# Time to first byte over 40 seconds on only one page

Tags: centos, cpanel, whm

First thank you for all the members of this great community. 
I have some awkward problem. This page http://www.tophebergeur.com/hebergement/perl/ has TTFB of more than 40 seconds.

These are the info from http://www.webpagetest.org/result/150625_AS_188H/1/details/

```
Error/Status Code: 200
Client Port: 2034
Request Start: 0.426 s
DNS Lookup: 367 ms
Initial Connection: 59 ms
Time to First Byte: 34765 ms
Content Download: 21 ms
Bytes In (downloaded): 14.2 KB
Bytes Out (uploaded): 0.4 KB
```

But when I filter this list by country the problem of TTFB is gone `/hebergement/perl/canada/`

I was looking in the server logs but couldn't find where is the problem

Thanks in advance

Comment: Without providing any details about what is run there, there's no meaningful way to find out.

Comment: there  is nothing too complicated. Pulling data from MySQL database and using ajax. what is weird is that this is the only page that has this problem. thanks Garg :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved. Apparently it was a problem of Cache. I'M using CDN that failed to load the cache of this page. THank you all. And I apprecited your help :)